# Is there a native call on Mac OS X like SetForegroundWindow() on Windows?

Tags: c++, macos, qt, mfc

We are in the process porting a Windows/MFC application to Mac platform. We are using qt, final product is a bundled app. In MFC, there is a call

```
BOOL WINAPI SetForegroundWindow(HWND hWnd)
```

I understand in Linux/X, there is no equivalent to this call. However, I am wondering if in Mac, maybe there is a native call, can do the same.

[EDIT] The way we use it is to make this call from parent process, while the hWnd is the main window of a child process. The link is useful. Thanks a lot. Generally, it is a security concern if a process can manipulate the main window of another process in Linux/Mac. But if any trick can bring up the main window of a child process, will be great.

Any help will be appreciated very much.

Comment: Also, it's typically bad practice (and incredibly annoying) for applications to steal focus this way.

Comment: There is a valid user request for this, the application launch two processes to display video/image side by side. User expect newly created process having windows on top of my old application.

Comment: All the appropriate focus changing behavior is built-in to the native API (e.g., opening a file with the `NSWorkspace` method `-openFile:` et al. will activate the appropriate application), but I guess Qt doesn't handle that. Instead of trying to emulate the built-in behavior (which will be hard to do perfectly) you might look into just using the native API for launching those processes.